# Deep linking on ios with Capacitor - "Error no apps with domain entitlements"

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, deep-linking, capacitor

I have a problem with Deep links in iOS using capacitor. Everything it's ok with Android but ios don't work.
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links

I've done all the needed steps:

added "associated domains" capability
created apple-app-site-association file.
uploaded the file on https
added on xcode the applinks:yourdomain.com that I need

Using this tool it's all ok but not one step. I have this error "Error no apps with domain entitlements"
https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation.../
I'm guessing that the problem is that when I added a feature the provisioning profile created earlier was invalidated. I need to create another provisioning profile also only for testing purposes?

Comment: Can you show some code samples? Or screenshots?

Comment: Did you manage to find to solve this?

Comment: nope. the error is still here BUT the deep linking works good. @GustavoSantamaría